# Java. Need to read file twice

Tags: java

I am new in programming world and now I am writing a simple code to read a text file which in each line stores student name and age. And for some reason I need to read that file twice, so I want to ask is there an easier way to do that than this?

```
File inputFile = new File("students.txt");

try {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (inputFile);

    // count how many lines are in the file
    while (in.hasNext())
    {
        in.nextLine();
        count++;
    } 

    in.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println ("Check your file mate");
}

ArrayStudent s = new ArrayStudent(count);

try {
    Scanner in2 = new Scanner (inputFile);

    while (in2.hasNext())
    {
        String name = in2.next();
        int age = in2.nextInt();
        s.insertStudent(new Student (name, age));
    } 

    in2.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println ("Check your file mate");
}
```

Comment: How is ArrayStudent defined? Why not just use a dynamic list, like an ArrayList or even a HashSet?

Comment: I thought about array list, but the thing is this is one from the weekly tasks at uni and we are only allowed to edit this part of code (ArrayStudentTester.java in this case) not any other file and ArrayStudent.java requires number of students for constructor. That is why I am asking, because I believe there must by another way than using opening / closing file twice. Thank you for your time

Comment: @eli: This a bit offtopic: But although I am an experienced full time software developer > 15 years employed, I have done last week a similar thing: I had to read a file two times, but for more complex reason. So you are not alone. ;-)

Comment: @eli-0 You can always just ignore the constructor argument :P

Comment: @eli: when you mzst use the studentArray, then yiu can first use my approach, and then after the list is fully read, you can iterate over the list and create the StudentArray

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler way, where you need to read the file only once

Instead of ArrayStudent which seems to have a fixed size array, use

```
 List<Student> students
```

ArrayList grows automatically as you add elements.

You initialize with

```
students= new ArrayList<Student>();
```

and add student to the list with

```
students.add(new Student(name, age));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not copy-and-paste your code. Use functions (methods) instead. You can create your own method that opens file and returns you a `Scanner` instance. In this case you will not create duplicate code.

Second, `Scanner` has constructor that accepts input stream. You can use `mark()` and `reset()` on input stream (see `FileInputStream`) to start reading from the beginning of the file.

Comment: mark(), reset() works on FileInputStream , but not on all streams. In fact such files often are stored in a data base, and when an InputStream is provided, it is not garuanteed that reset() works. (Last week I had such a case)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read the file twice at all. I'm assuming your `ArrayStudent` class contains a `Student[]` array. Instead you should be using a dynamically resizable data structure such as an `ArrayList`.

With the `ArrayList`, you won't need to have any prior knowledge of how many elements are going to be added to it; it automatically increases its size behind the scenes.

Here's an example of its usage:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
students.add(new Student(name1, age1));
students.add(new Student(name2, age2));
students.add(new Student(name3, age3));
```